# Marginal probability density function for a Joint Variable with two upper bounds

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

My joint variable function is 
$f(x,y) = \frac{2x+y}{36}$,  $ 0 \leq y \leq x$, $x + 2y \leq 6$, zero otherwise.

My question is when trying to find the marginal p.d.f. of X, how can I do that when y has two upperbounds. Do I have to find the higher upperbound or the lower bound?

Otherwise the answer can be written as

$$f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{6-2y} f(x,y)
\quad \textrm{ or } \quad
f_X(x) = \int_{0}^{y} f(x,y)?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to integrate with respect to $y$, so the bounds need to be functions in $x$, which the parameter of the marginal pdf.

Now, $x+2y\leqslant 6$ is equivalent to $y\leqslant 3-x/2$, so the support for this distribution is thus:
 $$\{\langle x,y\rangle: 0\leqslant x\leqslant 6\land 0\leqslant y\leqslant\min(x,3-x/2)\}$$
which is the triangle $\triangle(0,0)(2,2)(6,0)$, aka: $$\{\langle x,y\rangle: (0\leqslant x\lt 2~\land~ 0\leqslant y\leqslant x)\lor(2\leqslant x\leqslant 6~\land~ 0\leqslant y\leqslant 3-\tfrac x2\} $$

So $$f_X(x)=\mathbf 1_{x\in[0..2)}\int_0^x f(x,y)\mathsf d y+\mathbf 1_{x\in[2..6]}\int_0^{3-x/2} f(x,y)\mathrm d y$$

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

The first equation implies $y \le x$, the second implies $y \le 3-x/2$. Draw the region over which these bounds apply, and then your integral will separate in 2, one with one constraint and the other with the other...

Comment: Do you mean $y \leq 3-\frac{x}{2} $ ? In either case, I dont see how that separates into two integrals?